# Rewrite Engine Issue

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Respected Sir,

I am actually running phpserverslist script on my domain www.statstracker.in

When the .htaccess file was not present in the www directory the script was working fine but its rest menu's were not working. It used to say me URL Not Found.
But after adding.htaccess file with the below code the menu's started working:

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

But the problem now i m facing is every menu show me the homepage only. Even if i click on login menu it does'nt come up with login form it still directs me to the home index page.

What can i do??
All pages like login.php, register.php , etc are located in pages folder.

The script actually requires rewrite engine to be on. Even i made changes in httpd.conf file i changed from

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None

to

Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All